# Suppose $a$ and $b$ are positive real numbers with $a > b$ and $ab = 8.$ Find the minimum value of $\frac{a^2 + b^2}{a - b}.$

Tags: systems-of-equations

How would we go about minimizing this?
We can plug in $b = 8/a$ and go about minimizing the new expression but it isn't clear how to minimize.

What do you do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**HINT**

Since $a > b$, it results that $a - b > 0$. Consequently, we have that

\begin{align*}
\frac{a^{2}+b^{2}}{a-b} & = \frac{(a-b)^{2} + 2ab}{a-b}\\\\
& = a - b + \frac{2ab}{a-b}\\\\
& = a - b + \frac{16}{a-b}
\end{align*}

Now you can apply the AM-GM inequality.

Can you take it from here?

Comment: Got it thank you :)

Comment: @Patrick If this answered your question, mark the "answered" check next to it (and perhaps upvote it as well)